# How do I return an integer that is the sum of the integer values input in an ArrayList for Java at the indices 19, 9, and 14? So far I have:

Tags: java, arraylist

How do I return an integer that is the sum of the integer values input in an ArrayList for Java at the indices 19, 9, and 14? So far I have:
Write a public static method named q3 that takes an ArrayList of Integers as a       * parameter and returns an int. The returned int should be the sum of the values int the       * input ArrayList at indices 19, 9, and 14. You can assume the input ArrayList has size       * large enough to avoid an index out of bounds exception at these indices

```
public static int q3(ArrayList<Integers>) {     
ArrayList<Integers> thisList = new ArrayList<Integers>();   
thisList.add(9, "3");   
thisList.add(14, "0");  
thisList.add(19, "33");         

int sum = 0;    
int i = 0;
```

Comment: `List#add()` has nothing to do with arithmetic.

Comment: Use `thisList.get(9) + thisList.get(14) + thisList.get(19)`. You need to get the elements at the specified index

Comment: `list.stream().mapToInt().sum()` or some such hogwash. Java generics are nasty.

Comment: @JimGarrison The OP didn't claim that it has anything to do with arithmetic. The more severe problem seems to be that the above sequence of ASCII characters has nothing to do with Java, because function arguments are missing and all types are wrong...

Comment: @AluanHaddad The OP only wanted to sum elements from three indices

Comment: @user7 you're right. I was just trying to make it vaguely interesting

Comment: @AluanHaddad then you should have proposed `Stream.of(9, 14, 19).mapToInt(idx -> input.get(idx)).sum()` or some such hogwash...

Comment: That's a very unusual design choice. Unless there's more logic than the question mentions, why don't you consider creating a function that sums 3 integers, let's say `sumElements` and just call `sumElements(thisList.get(9), thisList.get(14), thisList.get(19))` ?

Comment: @tmeosky did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

Let me try to explain what a list is and how it works.
Imagine a list/array like a drawer cabinet, where each drawer has a number (index).

with `list.add(content)` you increase the size of the list and put `content` to the new drawer at the very last end (the automatically new created one).

with `list.add(index, content)` you put `content` into the drawer with the number `index` (and overwritwe any content in there before).

with `list.get(index)` you will get the content from the drawer with the number `index`.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // Create a empty list of numbers
numbers.add(8); // appends the number 8 to the list (the list gets bigger)
numbers.add(7); // appends the number 7 to the list (the list gets bigger)
numbers.add(6); // appends the number 6 to the list (the list gets bigger)

System.out.println(numbers); // {8,7,6}

numbers.add(0,11);
System.out.println(numbers); // {11,7,6}

System.out.println(numbers.get(0)); // 11
```

---

### Answer

Long simple readable version:

```java
public static int q3(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
   int sum = 0;
   sum = sum + list.get(19);
   sum = sum + list.get(9);
   sum = sum + list.get(14);
   return sum;
}
```

Version in short:

```java
public static int q3(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
   return (list.get(19) + list.get(9) + list.get(14));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static int q3(ArrayList<Integer> al) {
   int sum = al.get(19) + al.get(9) + al.get(14);
   return sum;
 }
```

Comment: What do you need the variable `sum` for?

Comment: to calculate sum of those three no. If you want you can directly return (al.get(19) + al.get(9) + al.get(14));

Comment: still doesn't look like valid Java... `<int>`?

Comment: So if I do this, I cannot call the method. Why is that?

Comment: I've added an import for an ArrayList, as well as a public static method

Comment: but if I call q3(); it is not valid

Comment: using ArrayList<Integer> will ask for adding Integer objects not no.s while with ArrayList<int> you can add integer numeric

Comment: how you are calling q3? can you give the parameters and rest of your code?

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ProblemSet_temeosky_0008{
public static int q3(ArrayList<Integer> al) {
    int sum=al.get(19)+al.get(9)+al.get(14);
        return sum;
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        q3();
}
}

Comment: You have to pass some arguments in the q3().it should be the arraylist object conatining Integer objects.